# Override parent style by a child compoent in Angular (mat-sidenav)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Is there a way to override side-nav content styles in some of the content component.

My side nav code below has `margin: 20px;` which I want to be overridden by only a couple of components loaded into the content section (eg: Map). One way is to remove the margin and apply it across all components individually except the Map. But I was wondering is there a way to go up the style hierarchy and override it from a child component. That is the opposite direction `\deep\`.

```
main {
  margin: 20px;
}


<mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container" autosize>
<mat-sidenav [opened]="true" #sidenav [mode]="sideNavMode">
  <mat-nav-list>
    <sidenav-list-item *ngFor="let navitem of navigationItems" [collapsed]="sidenavOpened" [navItem]="navitem"></sidenav-list-item>
  </mat-nav-list>
</mat-sidenav>
<main>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</main>
```

Here is a sample of what I am talking about. See the map component. It should override parent css.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-sidenav-generate-nav-mov9me?file=src/app/map/map.component.css

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to wrap each child that would modify the margin in a :host selector. You should be doing that anytime you're using a deep selector.

So in each child component that you're needing to modify this, you would do something like:

```
:host {
  /deep/ mat-sidenav-container {
    margin: 10px;
  }
}
```

Edit: In your case, I misunderstood the first time around until I looked at the running code! So with the map component being a child inside of the side-nav you'll need to use the `@at-root` reference to break out of the DOM tree and to the parent to reference the side-nav. Something like this:

```
:host {
  @at-root /deep/ .mat-drawer-inner-container {
    margin: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

You will need to change that `.css` file to `.scss` in order for this to work. And you will need to do this for every page you're wanting to make this "special".

Comment: what do you mean by this? Is there a sample? 'Your best bet is to wrap each child that would modify the margin in a :host selector. You should be doing that anytime you're using a deep selector.'

Comment: Yes, just like I placed in the answer. If you were to copy that and modify any of the material components, it would only be affected in that child component. Try something like background-color: black or something in the child component and you will see the change.

Comment: could you please look at this sample I created. I cant get it to work. Thanks
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-sidenav-generate-nav-mov9me?file=src/app/map/map.component.css

Comment: Updated my answer. Sorry, I didn't get back to this immediately.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-sidenav-generate-nav-udiy5j

Comment: Use Scss in root, you can override anything anywhere anytime. Using component styles to override deep styles in Angular is broken. You can also write query selectors in Javascript.

Comment: ok that worked. But this is not the solution I want. When I move to map the first time and move to the contacts component next, The contacts component ends up having styles that has been overridden by the Map component. But if I to contacts component after fresh reload it shows default styles. I want only map component to have this special case, while navigating back and forth to other components.